# Silverstripe dynamic page types

Tags: php, silverstripe

Am litle confused with new project. Am working site for one courses school.

**Course page:**

Courses page is added via administration `admin/pages/` and have own page type and data object. `Course`, `CoursePage`, `CourseCategory`. `CoursePage` has page model and controller where i have few methods for listing courses and categories. Also i have template `CoursePage.ss` and `CoursePage_details.ss`.
All courses `has one` course category.

Inside `CoursePage_Controller` i have two main methods:

```
 public function details(SS_HTTPRequest $request)

 public function ListAllCourses() {
    return Course::get();
 }
```

**Adding new courses:**

Adding new courses is done via `admin model`. I have `CourseAdmin` which extends `ModelAdmin` and all work good.

**Displaying courses:**

This is done via `Course_Controller` and `Course_Page.ss` and `Course_Page_details.ss`

Everything work fantastic but now problem is comming:

**Problem:**

My client want to create child pages inside `Courses` page and assign selected courses on a specific page.

So he want to create new child `Web development courses`  page and want to loop only courses for web development on that page.

Here i have problem becouse am adding courses via admin model. Next, all that sub page must have own page type like `WebDevelopmentPage` where i will query and filter that courses by category.

So if client want to add new child page and want to assign courses to that child page he must call me becouse i must create new page type and new page template for all that page, for that new child page! That is realy bad...

if there is a way that I could to filter the information through subpages? Or any trick to system automticly create new page type?

**Update:**

Solution 1:

I try this and work ok, but i think this is a bad practice.
Inside `Course` data object i add new `db` field `UrlSegment` where user must map some url segment like on page url. With what i will filter all on one page

```
 public function Courses()
    {
        if($this->URLSegment == "all-courses") {  
            return Courses::get();
        }else {
            $c = Courses::get()->filter(array(
                'UrlSegment' => $this->URLSegment
            ))->sort('Featured', 'DESC');

            return $c;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not let the client link the Course to the Page he wants (eg. with a `hay_many` or `many_many` relation)? This can be done with a GridField on the courses-subpage.

Comment: You can add a Courses 1:n CourseCategory relation and filter by it? No need to make seperate subpages, you can use an action in your Course_Controller to filter by it. See for example http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/controller-actions-dataobjects-as-pages and the other lessons listed there

Comment: My client want to have separated subpages. I already has `1:n` relation